# How can I cut the string based on the space?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, substring

I have this PHP code:

```
if ((strlen($str) > 120)){
        $str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ' ', 110)).' ...';
}
```

As you know, my code cuts the string based on the space. I mean it never ends up with cutting a word in the middle.

Anyway, I want to know, can I do the same thing in MySQL?

---

Based on some researches, I figured out there is a MySQL function for such job, something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 0, 110), other_cols
```

But as you know, it does't care about the space and might breaks a work.

Comment: You can use regex in MySQL do what you want.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Agreed, RegEx would be a nice option, just what's your opinion about answer below using `LOCATE()` function ?

Comment: I like it, clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start from something like this and adapt it for your needs:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LOCATE(' ' , YOURSTR, 120) > 0 
       THEN SUBSTR(YOURSTR, 1, LOCATE(' ' , YOURSTR, 120)) 
       ELSE YOURSTR END AS YOURSTR
FROM YOUR TABLE;
```

To answer at what you asked in comment below, try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LOCATE(' ' , 'abcd efg', 5) > 0 THEN SUBSTR('abcd efg', 1, LOCATE(' ' , 'abcd efg', 5)) ELSE 'abcd efg' END AS STR;
//=> 'abcd'

SELECT SUBSTR('abcdefg', 1, LOCATE(' ' , 'abcdefg', 5)) AS STR;
//=> ''

SELECT SUBSTR('abcd efg', 1, LOCATE(' ' , 'abcd efg', 50)) AS STR;
//=> ''
```

Comment: Clever .. thank you, upvote. Just I don't understand, what's the reason of that `CASE WHEN`? I guess this `SUBSTR(YOURSTR, 1, LOCATE(' ' , YOURSTR, 120))` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: `:-)` Thanks for editing, but what you mean exactly by those three queries?

Comment: try them and you can see results